# Run Java code once every hour

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks

I'm tryng to write a simple Java program that runs some code every hour when the minute hand is at 20. The issue is that that the way I'm doing it is incredibly CPU intensive. I'm familiar with Quartz but I'm looking for a much simpler solution, any ideas?

```
    boolean run = true;
    while(run){
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if(minute == 20){
            //Do some Stuff             
        }
    }
```

Comment: What system are you on? On linux, you could probably schedule a cron job of sorts.

Comment: Update: The terrible `Calandar` has been supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the Executors framework:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
s.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, secondsToFirstOccurence, 60*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And use some logic to find out `secondsToFirstOccurence`. This will probably involve a `Calendar` instance, but would be much more convenient with JodaTime.

Comment: Would this alternative play nice within a managed environment? would it synchronously block the current thread? if the answer to either question is "yes", I'd recommend against it, preferring an asynchronous service external to the container - like Quartz.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Quote OP: "I'm tryng to write a simple Java program". Adapt your advice to the context, please.

Comment: I ask because the question is tagged java-ee , so I assumed that the "simple application" lives inside a JEE container - making it not-so-simple after all.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It was also tagged "eclipse" and "algorithm", so go figure. I googled around for Quartz and the second hit is [this page](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz): "Why you shouldn't use Quartz Scheduler".

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that if your application is running inside a managed environment (a web or ejb container) you're not allowed to use `Thread.sleep()` or any other thread-related operations, for that matter, take a look at the [EJB restrictions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/restrictions-142267.html) page. I warn about this because the question is tagged `java-ee`, so the "simple application" might not be so simple after all - if it's running inside a Java EE container there are additional considerations to take care of.

If you're building an enterprise-grade application, forget about `Thread.sleep()`. Go for a full-fledged job scheduler, Use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), it's an open source and extremely mature and reliable product. Or use [Obsidian Scheduler](http://obsidianscheduler.com/), a feature-rich commercial scheduler with more out-of-the-box features than Quartz.

A lightweight alternative to a full-fledged scheduler (but suitable for running inside a container) would be to use the [Timer service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

Comment: The second paragraph is news to me. Care to give a source?

Comment: That covers the EJB case, but does that hold for any web container? For instance, the Servlet specification talks about "application created threads" (Servlet 3.0 spec, page 104).

Comment: No threads should be created, destroyed or manipulated in any way inside a managed environment. Even though you _can_, you _should not_ - doing so messes with the container's ability to control resources

Comment: @meriton Just consider what it takes to make application undeployment predictably safe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If Quartz can stop a worker thread when the context is destroyed, so can I ... or were you referring to something else?

Comment: @meriton We are talking about the same thing. I don't claim you are not allowed, or shouldn't, create your threads in a servlet. I am emphasizing the possible consequences, which explains why someone else may claim that you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) between calls

Answer (score 1):

Look at [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) method scheduleAtFixedRate().

Comment: There is explicit `schedule` method by `Date`

Comment: Well ExecutorService are latest and better than Timer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you remove the scheduling logic from your java program.
 By doing this you are able to focus only on what you want your program to do and leave the scheduling part to the OS. 
Also, say for example you decide at some point to write a c++ program that does what your java code does know, you won't have to implement the cron logic in your new program
That being said:

- for Linux you have [crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)
- for Windows you have [windows task schedule](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)
- for Mac, I am not sure, but given the fact it is UNIX based cron should be present.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in an infinite while and use

```
Thread.sleep(3600000);
```

Start the execution at 20 after

**Example**

```
while(1==1) {
    //Your code here
    try{
         Thread.sleep(3600000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that it will run on the 20th minute of the hour

Comment: I've tried this but I find that Thread.sleep is not always precise.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a cron job for the method that you want to execute hourly rather going for blocking `sleep()` call, Use some scheduling framework like [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: Why would you want the cron job to run yearly?

Answer (score 0):

1) On first entry calculate next due time.

2) Use [java.util.Timer.schedule()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29)

3) Reschedule each run.

**Code**

```
package tests;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class App201210130040 {


private static Timer timer = new Timer(false);

public static void schedule() {
    Calendar due = Calendar.getInstance();
    due.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
    if( due.before(Calendar.getInstance()) ) {
        due.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    }

    System.out.println("Scheduled to " + due.getTime().toString());

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("due");

            schedule();
        }

    }, due.getTime());

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    schedule();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at  [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
class BeeperControl {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
        };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = 
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
}
}
```

Comment: The main challenge is calculating the initial delay, to make it occur at the 20-min mark.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You got your point. He can schedule it for the first time as a dry run in which nothing will happen and then onwards it will start processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date time = calendar.getTime();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new SomeTask(), time);
```

and then reschedule

Answer (score 0):

So definitely the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is fantastic as many of the other answers state.

In the event you're in a Java EE 6 server, you could have some fun with `@Schedule` and `ScheduleExpression`

See [Have an EJB schedule tasks with "crontab syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361889/have-an-ejb-schedule-tasks-with-crontab-syntax/7365953#7365953)

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestHour {

    private static final int MINUNTE = 20;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            SimpleDateFormat bartDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
            Date date = new Date();
            int currentMin = new Integer(bartDateFormat.format(date))
                    .intValue();
            if (currentMin < MINUNTE) {
                sleepMinutes(MINUNTE - currentMin);
            } else if (currentMin > MINUNTE) {
                sleepMinutes(60 - currentMin + MINUNTE);
            } else {
                // DO SOMETHING EVERY HOUR
                System.out.println("come on do it!!!");
                sleepMinutes(60);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void sleepMinutes(int minutes) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping for " + minutes);
            Thread.sleep(minutes * 1000*60);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet even another example with the things learned today.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SchedulerExample2 implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Calendar due = Calendar.getInstance();
        due.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        due.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        due.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        if (due.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            due.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        }
        long milliSecondsToNextOcurrence =  due.getTimeInMillis() - new Date().getTime();
        final ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ShedulerExample task = new  ShedulerExample();
        s.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, milliSecondsToNextOcurrence, 60*60*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            System.out.println("hola->"+new Date());
    }   
}
```