# How to display JSON list for each hour of day - Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am mapping JSON data to object model in SpringBoot, looping through it and displaying it in the console.

What I am trying to do next is display JSON data FOR EACH HOUR OF THE DAY.

I googled trough what's online like this existing question but unfortunately I was not able to apply it.

[Run Java code once every hour - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866614/run-java-code-once-every-hour)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I started with something like this in my model class.

```
public class CarResponse {
    List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public List<Car> getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(List<Car> car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear();
        for (c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)) {
            System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
            String str = "=================================\r\n";
            for (Car ld : car) {
                str += "\t" + "Shop: " + ld.getShop() + "\r\n";
                str += "\t" + "Date: " + ld.getDate() + "\r\n";
                str += "\t" + "Values: " + ld.getValues() + "\r\n";
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

With code above I didn't get what I wanted. Well to explain better I don't have an error, but I would like my data to be displayed in the console like this:

```
2021-02-26T00:00+01:00[Europe/Vienna]
=================================
    Market: Audi
    Date: 12321599600000
    Values: []
=================================
2021-02-26T00:00+02:00[Europe/Vienna]
    Market: Audi
    Date: 12321599600000
    Values: []
```

Right now I get the output like this:

```
2021-02-26T00:00+01:00[Europe/Vienna]
2021-02-26T00:00+01:00[Europe/Vienna]
    =================================
        Market: Audi
        Date: 12321599600000
        Values: []
        Market: Audi
        Date: 12321599600000
        Values: []
```

Comment: A `for` loop in Java uses semi-colon character as delimiter, not comma.

Comment: Never use `Calendar`, part of the terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well I am very new to this... how should I use it then? Any code advice appreciated :)

Comment: Yes I did modify it a bit since posting question. But small changes. So I would like for each hour of the day that data from my JSON is showed. Do you maybe have any idea how can I do it?

Comment: Hi @OleV.V. I updated my question I hope this time it will work. I am here for questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Also, I recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for such a case because repeated string concatenation in a loop creates additional as many instances of `String`  as the number of concatenation. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat) to learn more about it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start of the day
        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(zdt.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
            zdt = zdt.plusHours(1);
            sb.append(zdt.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-26T00:00Z[Europe/London]
2021-02-26T01:00Z[Europe/London]
2021-02-26T02:00Z[Europe/London]
...
...
...
2021-02-26T22:00Z[Europe/London]
2021-02-26T23:00Z[Europe/London]
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I used your code, you can see it in my question update. What am I missing here :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem (apart from using the poorly designed and long outdated date classes as explained in the other answer) is the `return` statement inside your outer for loop.

This statement causes your `toString` method to exit:

```
        return str;
```

Only the string built up through the first time through the outer `for` loop is returned. The subsequent expected iterations of the loop never even happen.

Instead you need to declare `str` outside (that is, before) the first `for` loop. And only return it after that loop has ended, run to completion.

You may also consider using a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, but that’s a different story. Edit: There is already an example of using `StringBuilder` in the other answer. As you can see there, you may chain calls to its `append` method:

```
        sb.append(zdt.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
```

In your case you may want to use a longer chain, for example something like:

```
        sb.append("\t").append("Shop: ").append(ld.getShop()).append("\r\n")
            .append("\t").append("Date: ").append(ld.getDate()).append("\r\n")
            .append("\t").append("Values: ").append(ld.getValues()).append("\r\n");
```

Your `toString` method must return a `String`. Just use the `StingBuilder`’s `toString` method for that:

```
    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: @user9347049 `StringBuilder` is already used nicely in the other answer, so I have added but a small supplement in mine. Your search engine will find numerous other code examples.